# Hibernate 4 Deep Clone

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to do a Deep Clone with one Object with 3 different childs (OneToMany),

I'm doing this task with "SerializationHelper.clone" from Hibernate, but I only can copy the Parent and the child's not, with this code the id of the Child's change to the new Parent, and this is not good.

Where is the error, or what is the best practice for this task in Hibernate 4

```
template = (Template) session.get(Template.class,Integer.valueOf(idTemplate));

template.setTextboxes(template.getTextboxes());
template.setVariables(template.getVariables());

Template clone = (Template) SerializationHelper.clone(template);

session.save(clone);
```

**EDITED:** For the Childs, I have OneToMany Unidirectional Relationship:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "template_id") 
private Set<Variable> variables = new LinkedHashSet<Variable>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "template_id")
private Set<TextBox> textboxes = new LinkedHashSet<TextBox>();
```

Comment: "But I only can copy the Parent and the child's not, with this code the id of the Child's change to the new Parent, and this is not good." This is not a contradiction? The childs are copied or not? Some ID (FK?) is changed after the clone?

Comment: A mean, Test Case: id 1 - Template with 2 Textboxes and 1 Variable, the copy should be id 2  Template with 2 Textboxes and 1 Variable, but not is:  id 1 - Template and id 2  Template with 2 Textboxes and 1 Variable, somewhere Hibernate change the original Id of the Textboxes and Variables, it's not really a copy. Not, the code you see is the all I have before to save.

Comment: What the `@Id` code of `Variable` and `TextBox`?

Comment: the code of this two Objects is very basic, typical Pojo.. only annotations like @Column, I think Hibernate 4 don't support a deep clone natively.